# How to find the number of days difference using Google Script

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, timestamp

I was trying to find the difference between two days, I'm getting NaN.

```
function formatDate(oldFormat,duration,timestamp){
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(oldFormat, "IST","yyyy,MM,dd");
  Logger.log(timestamp);
  var newDate=new Date(timestamp*1000);
  Logger.log(newDate);
  newDate=Utilities.formatDate(newDate,"IST","yyyy,MM,dd");
  Logger.log(formattedDate);
  Logger.log(newDate);
  var date1=new Date(formattedDate).getTime();
  Logger.log(date1)
  var date2=new Date(newDate).getTime();
  Logger.log(date2)
  var diff=daydiff(date2,date1);
  Logger.log(diff);   }

 function daydiff(first, second) {
 return (second-first)/(1000*60*60*24);}
```

How to find the difference between two date in days? I've date in this format :
date 1 : 2015,05,12

date 2: 2015,05,28

Comment: First of all you will need a script that will fix the format of the dates to mm/dd/yyyy. You can pull in for example" 2015,05,28", split it by comma's and then combine with "/" in the correct order.

Comment: @AkshinJalilov I did this, but im getting output as 5884. but the actual output will be 16 days right?

Comment: Check my answer, as I wrote the script for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point to use **Utilities.formatDate()** as it is meant to convert a normal date in to any format, not the other way round.

Also not sure what **(oldFormat,duration,timestamp)** stand for. You do not use **duration** in your script, and both dates you showed seem to be the same format.

If you are simply trying to find the difference between two dates, try this:

```
function formatDate(date1,date2){
  date1 = new Date(fixDate(date1));
  date2 = new Date(fixDate(date2));
  var diff = (date2-date1)/(1000*60*60*24);
  return(diff);
}

function fixDate(date){  
    var collector = date;
    if (collector.match(",")!=null){
      collector = collector.split(",");
      var myString = [collector[1], collector[2], collector[0]].join("/");
      return myString
    }
  }
```